# how to create an expression indexed in CPLEX and C++

Tags: c++, cplex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otxIS.png)
i have this expression of a tour of worker and i tried to coded it and i don't know if it is correct or no because i have many errors so can someone help me ,
X[w][w][i][j] is a decision variable , p [i][j] is the weight of processing arc from i to j and d[i][j] is a distance

this is my proposition of code

```
compteur = 0;
        IloFloatVarArray2 CW(env, W);
        for (w = 0; w < W; w++)
        {
        CW[w] = IloFloatVarArray(env, W, 0.0, INFINITY);
            model.add(CW[w]);
#ifdef DEBUG
            for (w = 0; w < W; w++)
            {
                sprintf(varname, "CW_%d_%d", w, w);
                CW[w][w].setName(varname);
                compteur++;
            }
        }
#endif
#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("compteur cw =%d\n", compteur);
#endif

        IloExpr CW[w][w](env);

        for (i = 0; i < A; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < A; j++)
                CW[w][w] += d[i][j] * xW[w][i][j][w];
        for (i = 0; i < A; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < A; j++)
                CW[w][w] += Parc[i][j] * xW[w][i][j][w];
        for (i = 0; i < A; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < A; j++)
                CW[w][w] += 1 * xW[w][i][j][w];
        model.add(env, CW[w][w]);
                CW[w][w].end();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a 2-D array of expressions, fill it, and then constrain the expressions by some constraints. For example:

```
#include <ilcp/cp.h>

int main() {   
  typedef IloArray<IloNumExprArray> IloNumExprArray2;
  IloEnv env;
  IloInt n = 4;
  IloNumExprArray2 c(env, n);
  IloIntVarArray var(env, n, 0, n-1); 
  for (IloInt x = 0; x < n; x++) {
      c[x] = IloNumExprArray(env, n); 
      for (IloInt y = 0; y < n; y++) {
          c[x][y] = IloNumExpr(env, 0); 
          c[x][y] += var[x] * var[y];
      }
  }
  IloModel mdl(env);

  for (IloInt x = 0; x < n; x++) {
      for (IloInt y = 0; y < n; y++) {
          mdl.add(c[x][y] ==1);
      }
  }
  IloCP cp(mdl);
  cp.startNewSearch();
  while (cp.next()) {
      cp.out() << cp.domain(var) << std::endl;
  }
  cp.end();
  env.end();
  return 0;
}
```